# print the duplicate lines using the sed command?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am trying to print the duplicate lines in a file using the sed command.
In a file I have the following contents:

```
hi
hello
hi
how
hello
```

how can I print the duplicate lines in this file using sed command??

example: the output should be:

```
hi
hello
```

Comment: Not sure this can be done with sed. sed works on a single line at once and I'm not sure there's a way to safe a pattern (i.e. the contents of a line in your case), let alone a potentially infinite number of patterns, to compare them to the current line.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why it has to be in `sed` when you can use the `uniq` binary. Anywho, the file needs to be sorted so we have to do that first.

Using `uniq` and my preferred way:

```
$ sort file | uniq -d
hello
hi
```

Using `GNU sed`:

```
$ sort file | sed '$!N; s/^\(.*\)\n\1$/\1/; t; D'
hello
hi
```

- We read the next line from input with the `N` command which appends the next line to pattern space separated by "\n" character.
- `$!` prevents it from doing on the last line.
- The substitution replaces two repeating strings with one.
- The `t` command takes the script to the end where the current pattern space gets printed automatically.
- If the substitution was not successful, `D` executes, deleting the non-repeated string.
- The cycle continues and this way only the duplicate lines get printed once.

You can use process substitution if you please by doing `<(sort file)` to remove pipes.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -d
```

Sort the file and then print duplicate lines. If you wish to ignore the case then use -i option in uniq command.